# How can I easily convert HTML special entities from a standard input stream in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed, html

CentOS

Is there an easy way to convert HTML special entities from a data stream? I'm passing data to a bash script and sometimes that data includes special entities. For example:

> "test" &amp; test $test ! test @ # $ % ^ &amp; *

I'm not sure why some characters show up fine and other don't but unfortunately, I don't have control over the data coming in.

I'm thinking I might be able to use SED here but that seems like it would be cumbersome and possibly prone to false positives. Is there a Linux command I could pipe to that specializes in decoding this type of data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP is well suited to this. This example requires PHP 5:

```
cat file.html | php -R 'echo html_entity_decode($argn);'
```

Comment: This command strips the new lines from my output, which is not wanted in some cases.

Answer (score 14):

Perl is (as always) your friend.
I think this will do it:

```
perl -n -mHTML::Entities -e ' ; print HTML::Entities::decode_entities($_) ;'
```

E.g.:

```
echo '"test" &amp; test $test ! test @ # $ % ^ &amp; *' |perl -n -mHTML::Entities -e ' ; print HTML::Entities::decode_entities($_) ;'
```

With output:

```
someguy@somehost ~]$ echo '"test" &amp; test $test ! test @ # $ % ^ &amp; *' |perl -n -mHTML::Entities -e ' ; print HTML::Entities::decode_entities($_) ;'
"test" & test $test ! test @ # $ % ^ & *
```

Comment: This works on my OSX10.8 laptop and a RHEL5.something host.

Comment: In order to output the file in UTF-8, use binmode:
    echo "&laquo;" | perl -n -mHTML::Entities -mutf8 -e 'binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8"); print HTML::Entities::decode_entities($_) ;'

Answer (score 11):

[recode](https://github.com/pinard/Recode) seems available on default packages repositories of main GNU/Linux distributions.  E.g. to decode HTML entities into UTF-8 :

```
…|recode html..utf8
```

Edit : The initial repo [looks unmaintained](https://github.com/pinard/Recode/issues/16), a more up-to-date fork can be found [here](https://github.com/rrthomas/recode).

Comment: unfortunately this messes up UTF-8 (e.g. zero-width spaces...)

Comment: @ciis0 See my edit, does it happen with the fork ?  If so, it might be worth filing an issue on gitlab.  Not sure which version is implemented in standard distributions, though, I wouldn’t be surprised it’s still the initial version.

Comment: seems to be the initial one; I used `apt install recode` on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 5):

With Python 3:

```
python3 -c 'import html,sys; print(html.unescape(sys.stdin.read()), end="")' < file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Takes text file from stdin:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
while read lin; do
  newl=${lin//&gt;/>}
  newl=${newl//&lt;/<}
  newl=${newl//&amp;/<}
  # ...other entites
  echo "$newl"
done
```

It probably needs bash >= version 4

Answer (score 0):

I use this script. Save it as `html2utf.py`, and use it ala `echo $some_html | html2utf.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
An alternative for `perl -Mopen=locale -MHTML::Entities -pe '$_ = decode_entities($_)'` (which you can use by `cpanm HTML::Entities`) and `recode html..`.
"""

import fileinput
import html

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(html.unescape(line.rstrip('\n')))
```